# Conflictos entre Ajax y angular 2

Tags: ajax, angularjs-2.0, angular-cli

Estoy enviando un formulario con AJAX y todo funciona bien, el problema es que necesito almacenar la respuesta de AJAX en un variable de Angular2.

**Mi código :**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    this.miVariableAngular = this.responseText; 
};
```

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error surge ya que el programa cree que al utilizar **this.miVariableAngular** estoy llamando un método de AJAX, ya que confunde el THIS de la variable angular con el THIS de referencia a la respuesta de AJAX.

¿Como puedo asignar esa respuesta en una variable de angular 2?

Agradezco de antemano su colaboración,

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer que onreadystatechange sea un arrow function:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = (e => {
  this.miVariableAngular = this.responseText; 
})
```